ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.26.0` but I have version already installed 1.0.1
I'm trying to run traning this way but face import error, how to fix it:
args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="finetuned",
                          num_train_epochs=10,
                          per_device_train_batch_size=16,
                          save_steps=10000,
                          gradient_accumulation_steps = 2,
                          warmup_steps=500,
                         lr_scheduler_type="polynomial",
                         fp16=True,
                         )

trainer = Trainer(
    model = model,
    args = args,
    train_dataset = train_dataset,
    eval_dataset = test_dataset,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,

)


trainer.train()

However it gives me such error:
File ~\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\transformers\training_args.py:1750, in TrainingArguments.__post_init__(self)
   1748 # Initialize device before we proceed
   1749 if self.framework == "pt" and is_torch_available():
-> 1750     self.device
   1752 if self.torchdynamo is not None:
   1753     warnings.warn(
   1754         "`torchdynamo` is deprecated and will be removed in version 5 of  Transformers. Use"
   1755         " `torch_compile_backend` instead",
   1756         FutureWarning,
   1757     )

File ~\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\transformers\training_args.py:2250, in TrainingArguments.device(self)
   2246 """
   2247 The device used by this process.
   2248 """
   2249 requires_backends(self, ["torch"])
-> 2250 return self._setup_devices

File ~\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\generic.py:60, in cached_property.__get__(self, obj, objtype)
     58 cached = getattr(obj, attr, None)
     59 if cached is None:
---> 60     cached = self.fget(obj)
     61     setattr(obj, attr, cached)
     62 return cached

File ~\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\transformers\training_args.py:2123, in TrainingArguments._setup_devices(self)
   2121 if not is_sagemaker_mp_enabled():
   2122     if not is_accelerate_available():
-> 2123         raise ImportError(
   2124             f"Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>={ACCELERATE_MIN_VERSION}`: "
   2125             "Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install 'accelerate>={ACCELERATE_MIN_VERSION}'`"
   2126         )
   2127 # We delay the init of `PartialState` to the end for clarity
   2128 accelerator_state_kwargs = {"enabled": True, "use_configured_state": False}

ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.26.0`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install 'accelerate>={ACCELERATE_MIN_VERSION}'`

but I have right version:
import accelerate    
accelerate.__version__

> '1.0.1'


transformers.__version__ 
> transformers


Are you using a virtual envirement?

You probably use different environments for pip and python interpreter

Just create a new conda environment and install everything from scratch. As to the cause of your issue, it could be that you were using the wrong python environment by accident, it could also be a failed pip upgrade. A lot of mistakes can lead to this outcome. Creating a new environment step by step from scratch can fix anything.

Restarting the kernel after upgrading both transformers and accelerate solved it for me.
